# Why do I get "Log is disabled" when I try to access my wsdl?

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, wsdl, soapui

I have deployed a war from a project in SoapUI. I upload it to my Tomcat server and when I try to access it instead of my wsdl I get :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SoapUI MockServices Log for project [XXXX]</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Log is disabled.</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why is that happening? I have a feeling this is caused by some setting in SoapUi, how do I fix it? I've tried the same thing with other projects and I've had no issues.